# Using -exec with kill command

Tags: grep, kill

I am trying to execute the following command in which I use the kill and exec commands.

```
kill -l -exec grep -i 'term' {} +
```

**Since, kill -l returns a list of all kill signals, I want to find all those signals which contain the word 'term' using grep with case insensitive -i flag**. But, it returns the following errors. Could someone advise why could this be?

```
-bash: kill: grep: invalid signal specification
-bash: kill: -i: invalid signal specification
15
-bash: kill: {}: invalid signal specification
-bash: kill: +: invalid signal specification
```

Comment: What are these supposed to do? `-exec` looks what you'd use with `find`, what does `kill` have to do with it? Do you just want to pipe kill to grep?

Comment: @muru The way I understood was that -exec acts on the output of an another command ( the command being kill -l) which returns the output of kill signals. From there, I want to find all those kill signals which contain the terminate (term) keyword.

Comment: There is no generic `-exec` - `find` has a `-exec` which runs commands, but I don't know of other commands that have such an option. Do you just want to do `kill -l | grep ...`?

Comment: @muru yes, that's basically what I wanted to do but with the -exec command. So, -exec is available only with the find command?

Comment: Yes, because `-exec` is not a command. There is an `exec` command but you can't use either of them as options to random commands and expect them to work.

Comment: @muru thanks. Got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-exec cmd {} +` is an idiom of the `find` command and the `find` command alone. It's used there to run `cmd` with the files it has *found* as arguments. `-exec` there is *not* an option, it's generally called a *predicate* and is used in the chain of conditions and actions that make up a `find` expression (`find` also supports options which are passed before the list of files / directories it should start finding from).

`kill` is a command that is builtin in most shells and used to send signals to processes based on their process ID or the shell job they're member of.

Most implementations also support a `-l` option which lists the signals that may be sent in a format that varies with the implementation. Some list signals one per line, some in column, some just space separated, some include both the the signal name and number.

If, in addition to the `-l` option, you pass a signal name or number (with or without the `SIG` prefix with some implementation), some `kill` implementations will output the corresponding signal number / name, though some always print the name, and some only accept numbers.

So:

```
kill -l TERM
```

for instance, with some `kill` implementations including the `kill` builtin of the `zsh` shell will output:

```
15
```

Where `15` on most if not all systems is the actual value of SIGTERM.

In the `zsh` shell, the signal names (+ EXIT which is also used in `trap`) are also available in the `$signals` special array:

```
$ echo $signals
EXIT HUP INT QUIT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE KILL USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM STKFLT CHLD CONT STOP TSTP TTIN TTOU URG XCPU XFSZ VTALRM PROF WINCH POLL PWR SYS ZERR DEBUG
```

The signal number for a given signal is its index in the array minus 1.

```
$ echo $signals[15+1]
TERM
$ echo $(( signals[(I)TERM] - 1 ))
15
```

Or for a case insensitive matching:

```
$ set -o extendedglob
$ echo $(( signals[(I)(#i)term] - 1 ))
15
```

(`kill -l term` also works in many `kill` implementations).

Answer (score 0):

With the `-l` option, the output of `bash`'s `kill` builtin when not in POSIX mode is:

```
$ kill -l
 1) SIGHUP        2) SIGINT       3) SIGQUIT      4) SIGILL
 5) SIGTRAP      6) SIGABRT      7) SIGEMT       8) SIGFPE
 9) SIGKILL     10) SIGBUS      11) SIGSEGV     12) SIGSYS
13) SIGPIPE     14) SIGALRM     15) SIGTERM     16) SIGURG
17) SIGSTOP     18) SIGTSTP     19) SIGCONT     20) SIGCHLD
21) SIGTTIN     22) SIGTTOU     23) SIGIO       24) SIGXCPU
25) SIGXFSZ     26) SIGVTALRM   27) SIGPROF     28) SIGWINCH
29) SIGINFO     30) SIGUSR1     31) SIGUSR2
```

I can group each pair `number) signal` with `xargs -n 2`

So this should do what you asked for:

```
kill -l | xargs -n 2 | grep -i term
```